# Keep data in the external folder for mongodb docker container

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am using [official docker container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/library/mongo/). Here is a [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/master/2.6/Dockerfile).
I am running container using this command:

```
docker run --name mongo-db -d -p 27017:27017 -v  /mnt/lacie/databases/mongo/data:/data mongo
```

Next I connect to mongodb, create a db, a collection and insert data on it.

I can stop the container `docker stop`, run it again `docker start` and all the data changes will be present in the database.

If I remove container `docker rm` and create new one - the data dissapear. Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

Based on [the current Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/497360ef391e4afb43ece00de79effb0fd062021/3.0/Dockerfile#L29) you need to mount under `/data/db` not just `/data`. Because of this mismatch your data is probably going into the container's private storage instead of into your mounted volume.

Comment: I have tried this version`docker run --name mongo-db -d -p 27017:27017 -v /mnt/lacie/databases/mongo/data/db:/data/db mongo`.  It doesn't work and I event don't have any files under `/mnt/lacie/database/data/db` folder in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging it like this:

```
docker run --name mongo-db -d -p 27017:27017 -v /data mongo
docker stop mongo-db
docker run --name mongo-db2 -d -p 27017:27017 --volumes-from mongo-db mongo
```

If that works, then there's in an issue in the way mongo db is storing the data (I see in the Dockerfile for example that it specified `/data/db` as a `VOLUME` so it might expect the rest of the `/data/` folder to be empty on initialization). That would probably be a bug but I'm just guessing without further info.

You can test my theory using:

```
docker run --name mongo-db -d -p 27017:27017 mongo
docker stop mongo-db
docker run --name mongo-db2 -d -p 27017:27017 --volumes-from mongo-db mongo
```

Comment: Both examples work, but it work until I have mongo container.  If I remove `mongo-db` container I can not to run `mongo-db2` using `--volumes-from mongo-db mongo` and lose all my data.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. the cause of the problem is not to use rm -f to remove the mongo container, we must to first command "stop" and then "rm" the mongo container.